# If nullity(A) <= nullity(B), can we infer the relation between the ranks of the two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

If nullity(A) $\leq$ nullity(B), can we infer the relation between the ranks of the two matrices?

Comment: Do you know anything about the sizes of $A$ and $B$?  Hint: Use the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Not without information as to the shape of each matrix.  Consider identity matrices of varying size... they all have nullity zero but different rank.

Comment: @JMoravitz, assume they both have the same number of columns but different number of rows

Comment: Still no.  You can only use $nullity(A)\leq nullity(B)$ to imply anything about the relationship between $A$ and $B$ if they are they same shape, i.e. both rows *and* columns are the same size.  You can find examples $A_1,A_2,B$ where the number of columns are same size but number of rows are different where $nullity(A_1)\leq nullity(B)$ as well as $nullity(A_2)\leq nullity(B)$ but where $rank(A_1)<nullity(B)$ and $rank(A_2)>nullity(B)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, Thank you. But can you express the example in terms of ranks, to make it clearer? "... but where $rank(A_1)<nullity(B)$ and $rank(A_2)>nullity(B)$."

Answer (score 0):

> "*Assume they both have the same number of columns but different number of rows*"

$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

$A_1$ has rank $3$ and nullity $0$

$A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

$A_2$ has rank $1$ and nullity $2$

$B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

$B$ has rank $2$ and nullity as large as we like, say for example if $B$ has $10^{100}+2$ rows $B$ would have nullity $10^{100}$

Here we have $nullity(A_1)\leq nullity(B)$ as well as $nullity(A_2)\leq nullity(B)$ since $3\leq 10^{100}$ as well as $1\leq 10^{100}$

However, despite both $nullity(A_1)$ and $nullity(A_2)$ being less than $nullity(B)$, that information alone does not tell us how the rank of $A_1$ or $A_2$ compare to $B$.  Here we have $rank(A_1)>rank(B)$ since $3>2$ while $rank(A_2)<rank(B)$ since $1<2$

---

If you knew that $A$ and $B$ were the same shape, then $nullity(A)\leq nullity(B)$ is true if and only if $rank(A)\geq rank(B)$.  This is seen as an immediate corrolary of the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: For an m x n matrix, say B, rank(B) + nullity(B) = n. In your example, B has a rank of 2 and n = 3, while is its nullity not equal to 1?

Comment: Are you not defining nullity as the dimension of the null space of the matrix, Bx = 0?